# Using Forms Authentication with dynamic directory / resource security

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, forms-authentication

I work on an Ektron CMS solution where our site implements a membership-based access model. There are certain resources that we publish that require a purchased membership to access, others you just need to register on the site, and some are free.

We use Ektron's Aliasing extensively, which is essentially URL rewriting. So, we have resources like /about/ that map to /default.aspx?id=1234, which is available to the public, but we also have resources like /surveys/ that map to /default.aspx?id=3456 that are restricted.

How would I implement the granular access to these resources using Forms Authentication depending on the resource that is requested?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap that url mapper, with a 'pre-mapper' that will forward unauthenticated users to different urls in case the target url is restricted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suppose it is possible that in a module that currently acts as a canonical redirect I could throw in some security checks there.